# SQL for tagging

Tags: sql

I have a table of clients that may be addressed to different department. Each client can be assigned to multi departments, and each department has multi clients.
Therefore I have a :

```
client table which includes (clientID,client info...)

departments table which includes a (departmentID,department info...) 

connecting table (assign_ID,client_ID,departmentID).
```

When looking for clients assigned to one of 2 departments the sql statment is simple:

```
select * from clients join connectingtable on... join departments on... where departmentID=1 or departmentID=2
```

But what do I do when I need an AND statement there. I need clients assigned to 2 departments at the same time. I can't replace the OR with AND because this will require that for each line I will have 2 IDs inserted which is not possible. How should I solve this?

Comment: Another solution would be `...GROUP BY clientid HAVING sum(departmentID=1)>0 AND sum(departmentID=2)>0`

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use two `EXISTS` clauses:

```
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT client_ID 
             FROM connecting c 
             WHERE departmentID = 1 
               and c.client_ID = connecting.client_id)   // or use alias from outer query instead of "concecting"
  AND EXISTS(SELECT client_ID 
             FROM connecting c 
             WHERE departmentID = 2 
               and c.client_ID = connecting.client_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use left join twice on departments and check if there are results in the first and second join.

```
SELECT * FROM Clients WHERE CliendID IN
    (SELECT CliendID 
     FROM clients join connectingtable on... 
     LEFT JOIN departments DEP1 on...
     LEFT JOIN departments DEP2 on...
     WHERE DEP1.departmentID IS NOT NULL AND DEP2.DepartmentID IS NOT NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest a query that is pretty similar to the one proposed by @Dejan but avoiding the IN(...) form:

```
SELECT *
FROM Clients C
INNER JOIN (SELECT C1.ClientID
      FROM Clients C1
      INNER JOIN connecting CT1 ON CT1.ClientID = C1.ClientID
      INNER JOIN departments D1 ON D1.DepartmentID = CT1.DepartmentID
                                  AND D1.departmentID = 1) DP1 ON DP1.ClientID = C.ClientID
INNER JOIN (SELECT C2.ClientID
      FROM Clients C2
      INNER JOIN connecting CT2 ON CT2.ClientID = C2.ClientID
      INNER JOIN departments D2 ON D2.DepartmentID = CT2.DepartmentID
                                  AND D2.departmentID = 2) DP2 ON DP2.ClientID = C.ClientID
```

Hope this is what you're looking for.

Answer (score -1):

```
select * from clients a
 where (select count(*) from connectingtable b
         where a.clientID = b.clientID) > 1
```

Comment: This won't help where there are two different values for `b.clientID`, which is the original poster's problem.

Comment: "I need clients assigned to 2 departments at the same time"

Comment: Based on the example query (ref: `where departmentID=1 or departmentID=2`) and the description of the problem (ref: "... I need an AND statement there. I need clients assigned to 2 departments at the same time") I think the problem is to find a client who is in both departmentId `1` and departmentId `2`, specifically - not any two departments. (Besides that, you have joined only as far as `connectingtable` and aren't looking for two different departments at all.)